# finding unique values from a list

Tags: list, r, unique

Suppose you have a list of values

```
x <- list(a=c(1,2,3), b = c(2,3,4), c=c(4,5,6))
```

I would like to find unique values from all list elements combined. So far, the following code did the trick

```
unique(unlist(x))
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way? I have a hefty list with a lot of values and would appreciate any speed-up.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This solution suggested by Marek is the best answer to the original Q. See below for a discussion of other approaches and why Marek's is the most useful.

```
> unique(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

#### Discussion

A faster solution is to compute `unique()` on the components of your `x` first and then do a final `unique()` on those results. This will only work if the components of the list have the same number of unique values, as they do in both examples below. E.g.:

First your version, then my double unique approach:

```
> unique(unlist(x))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> unique.default(sapply(x, unique))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

We have to call `unique.default` as there is a `matrix` method for `unique` that keeps one margin fixed; this is fine as a matrix can be treated as a vector.

Marek, in the comments to this answer, notes that the slow speed of the `unlist` approach is potentially due to the `names` on the list. Marek's solution is to make use of the `use.names` argument to `unlist`, which if used, results in a faster solution than the double unique version above. For the simple `x` of Roman's post we get

```
> unique(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Marek's solution will work even when the number of unique elements differs between components.

Here is a larger example with some timings of all three methods:

```
## Create a large list (1000 components of length 100 each)
DF <- as.list(data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 1000*1000, replace = TRUE), 
                                ncol = 1000)))
```

Here are results for the two approaches using `DF`:

```
> ## Do the three approaches give the same result:
> all.equal(unique.default(sapply(DF, unique)), unique(unlist(DF)))
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(unique(unlist(DF, use.names = FALSE)), unique(unlist(DF)))
[1] TRUE
> ## Timing Roman's original:
> system.time(replicate(10, unique(unlist(DF))))
   user  system elapsed 
  12.884   0.077  12.966
> ## Timing double unique version:
> system.time(replicate(10, unique.default(sapply(DF, unique))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.648   0.000   0.653
> ## timing of Marek's solution:
> system.time(replicate(10, unique(unlist(DF, use.names = FALSE))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.510   0.000   0.512
```

Which shows that the double `unique` is a lot quicker to applying `unique()` to the individual components and then `unique()` those smaller sets of unique values, but this speed-up is purely due to the `names` on the list `DF`. If we tell `unlist` to not use the `names`, Marek's solution is marginally quicker than the double `unique` for this problem. As Marek's solution is using the correct tool properly, and it is quicker than the work-around, it is the preferred solution.

The big gotcha with the double `unique` approach is that it will only work **if**, as in the two examples here, each component of the input list (`DF` or `x`) has the same number of unique values. In such cases `sapply` simplifies the result to a matrix which allows us to apply `unique.default`. If the components of the input list have differing numbers of unique values, the double unique solution will fail.

Comment: Check `system.time(replicate(10, unique(unlist(DF,FALSE,FALSE))))`. It's faster.

Comment: So it is. You only need `unique(unlist(DF, use.names = TRUE))` though to get the substantial speed up. I knew names on data frames was a source of slow down but it didn't occur to me that this would be a problem here. There isn't, as far as I can see, any recursion going on as `DF` and `x` only have a single level of components. You should post that as an answer as it uses the correct tools directly.

Comment: Improvement from 47 seconds to 0.05 seconds. I would call that significant. :)

Comment: @ucfagls You mean `unique(unlist(DF, use.names = FALSE))`? Please include it in your answer if you like it ;)

Comment: @Marek: oops, yes, I meant `unique(unlist(DF, use.names = FALSE))`. Will add your improvement to my answer with suitable attribution.

Comment: I've now added Marek's solution to my answer with timings. A note on why these timings have changed; These new ones were done on my workstation whilst the ones in the original email were done on a newer machine at home.

Comment: I though s(l)apply family works on each list element independently. How does one reconcile the above code where sapply compares values between list elements?

Comment: `sapply` applies `unique` to each component of `DF` and returns a matrix, each row representing the unique values in the individual components. We then treat the matrix as a vector and ask for the unique values from this much smaller set.

Comment: Of course, as I have just noted in the Answer, the double unique approach only works here if all the components have the same number of unique values. Marek's one works regardless.